# Identification of this plant. It grew around the garlic I planted and I'm not sure what it is

Tags: identification

I recently planted some garlic in a planter. The garlic died, but this sprouted up around it. I suspect it’s a type of lettuce, but I'm unsure because it doesn't really grow in a clump the way lettuce usually does.

[image: Is this a type of lettuce?]

Comment: Can you share a picture of the plant also?

Answer (score 4):

You're right that this is a leaf lettuce of some kind - this type of lettuce does not form heads and is sometimes referred to as "cut and come again" lettuce. When lettuce goes to seed the seed is dispersed via the wind, so it's possible, if this was an outside planter, that one of your neighbors' lettuces seeded your planter. Enjoy the free crop!

Comment: Yes, we grow it.  You can keep harvesting the outer leaves and it keeps growing

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate the information. I'm new to gardening and still experimenting. It sort of caught me off guard that I transplanted garlic to a pot and got lettuce instead! LOL!

Comment: @EarlGrayman Glad to help. I've let lettuce bolt and go to seed so that it plants itself in my vegetable garden for the following spring. Unfortunately, it also plants itself in some nearby flower beds too- but at least I can eat those weeds when I pull them. :)